# Is it possible to implement an express checkout with Drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I'd like to setup a product, where it's just a one page form customers fill out, and a button labelled 'Pay now'.

I don't want a list of products or add to cart functionality or anything like that. Just a simple form and a button. A confirmation page and email is fine.

Is it possible to do this with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a nice [tutorial on how to set up an EXPRESS CHECKOUT](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/express-checkout-drupal-commerce) using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
to bypass the add to cart stage.

I noticed there is a [Commerce Express Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_express_checkout) module, but I personally rather use rules to do it.

To display this on your home page, [using the views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) you'll need to create a **block view**  of your product and put it in your home page.

Comment: great, thanks. That worked fine. Now I need to turn the 'add to cart' button from 'add to cart' into a 'register now' link on the home page of the site. But that's probably off topic for this discussion and besides I haven't really researched it yet. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: how about adding an export of your rules, or the rules described in the tutorial? A rule (in export format) is worth more than 1000 words (in a manual), no?

Comment: `A rule (in export format) is worth more than 1000 words` @Pierre.Vriens  you're % right, I wish I had thought of it at the time.